# Need to setup emacs indentation mode

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs as my editor. 
I am trying to press 'tab' key to
1. correctly intent my code
2. replace tab with 4 spaces

I have this setup in my .emacs:

```
;; to setup tabs
(setq c-basic-indent 2)
(setq tab-width 4)
(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

but it does not do what I want. I go to a incorrect indented line, press tab. It indents the line correctly, but it does not replace tab with spaces.

How can I fix it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emacs normally does not change TABs to spaces.  `indent-tabs-mode` only controls whether TABs or spaces will be inserted when indentation spacing gets inserted, but existing spacing will be unaffected.

If you want to get rid of TABs, you can do `C-x h M-x untabify RET`.

Answer (score 0):

In brief:

- I don't think there's a `c-basic-indent` variable. Perhaps you meant to use `c-basic-offset` ?
- Assuming so, then *all* of those variables are automatically buffer-local. Using `setq` sets the value for the buffer which was active when that code was evaluated. You can set the default/global value using `setq-default`.